# AWS Eventbridge Rejects cron

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

Why isn't this a valid cron?

```
13 33 * * ? *
```

I'm trying to schedule an AWS Lambda function with EventBridge, and it keeps telling me that this is invalid, while this statement **is** valid:

```
13 20 * * ? *
```

Comment: It is because the second position relates to hours and only allows value from 0-23. Hence 33 is invalid. Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduled-events.html for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two number are Minutes then Hours. So you are asking for the time 33:13 which is invalid whereas 20:13 is fine.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html